# Bootstrap Carousel: edit the background to be plain black in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Just wondering, I have been attempting to make the background of my carousel pure black to match that of my overall website background but I can't seem to get this to work. It feels that I'm missing something obvious, but I can't for the life of me see what that is.

Here is my carousel css:

```
.carousel {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #000000;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-caption p {
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Here is my specific carousel html:

```
<!-- Carousel -->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="someimage" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Introducing astrobox</h1>
                                <p>sdfsdfsdf</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign Up</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="someimage" alt="Second slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                                <p>dfsdfsdf</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="someimage" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                                <p>sdfsdfsdf</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

If anyone knows exactly how to do this I would be very appreciative.

Comment: It looks black to me: http://www.bootply.com/GEKRGW7Ms1

Comment: @amphetamachine It must be some parent selector but I have a grey/white border around my carousel...

Comment: Every thing looks fine Carousel background is black [https://jsfiddle.net/uwh784xx/](https://jsfiddle.net/uwh784xx/)

Comment: @APAD1 & Niket Thapa --you're both running it full screen. Drop it in a container and the problem is obvious: [see this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/9DB39IDzj6)

Comment: @Ted Its contained in a border of Color ffffff

Comment: It doesn't matter what screen size I view it in, I do not see a border. There must be CSS elsewhere, which you did not post, which is creating the border.